# Can we use singular countable nouns after "any"?

Tags: grammaticality, countable-nouns

Which one is correct ?

1.A. There isn't any student in the class.

1.B. There aren't any students in the class.

how is that in questions?

2.A. Is there any student in the class?

2.B. Are there any students in the class?

Comment: As given, the "B" versions are better. Though you could have thought of better examples—there are ALWAYS students in the class; otherwise it wouldn't be a class!  But, the "A" versions become usable if a restrictive clause is added: Is there any student in the class **who likes chocolate**?

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect to have more than one student in a class you would say 1B:

> There aren't any students in the class.

But if you only expected one, you could use the singular:

> There isn't any teacher for the class.